# Can points not being passed to the loss function influence it?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, training, loss-function

If I were to construct a model where only a subset of the training data is passed to the loss function, can the other parts of the dataset influence the fit?

More concretely, in this first example:

```
model.fit(x_train_subset, y_train_subset, val=[x_val, y_val])
```

Here, I am passing the model, and then the loss function, only the subset to be trained on.

In another example:

```
model.compile(loss=CustomLoss) #this loss will be based on x_train_subset
model.fit(x_train, y_train, val=[x_val, y_val])
```

Here, I have passed the entire training set to the fit, but using only a subset of them to find the loss.

My questions are:

1. Conceptually, are these the same?
2. If a point is not being passed to the loss function is it effectively invisible to the model training procedure?

Answer (score 1):

1.Technically they are the same.They will compute the same loss. Although there will be a subtle difference in performance. In the first case gradient will only be calculated for the subset but in the second case gradient will be calculated for the whole training set but only the gradient of subset will be used to compute cost and update.

2.No, the points won't be invisible to the training procedure. the gradient will be calculated for all of the points but they won't be used.

Comment: thank you for the response! so, if I understand correctly: the final result for both methods will be the same, but how it gets to it (it calculating the gradient) will be different? And when you say "subtle difference in performance" do you mean how fast it will be calculated, or do you mean more in terms of a metric like accuracy?

Comment: the final result for both methods will be the same, but how it gets to it (it calculating the gradient) will be different and "subtle difference in performance"  means how fast it will be calculated,

Answer (score 1):

In the simple example you’ve given, the outcome should be similar. Not the same because default Keras batch size is 32 and whereas in the first formulation that would mean 32 usable training examples, in the second the model could only benefit from the percentage of the 32 that you allow the loss function to see.

I would prefer the first option where the subset of the training data is passed explicitly because

- layers that are trained but not by backpropagation (e.g. batch normalisation) will otherwise still see and use the whole set of training data
- you’ll have better control over things like batch size, because it will be clearer how many training examples are being passed in each training step
- your code will be easier to read if you are explicit about what training data is being used